# Xcode 4.5 building error: Malformed Object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, build-error

I'm trying to build a project with Xcode 4.5.1, created with Xcode 4.4, but I'm getting following error:

> codesign_allocate: for architecture armv7 object:
>   /Users/myUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAPP-araevdowzmmoupfieakjpjmpsmhq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyAPP.app/MyAPP
>   malformed object (unknown load command 36)
>   /Users/myUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Can somebody help me please?

Thank you!

**Update:**

I still have this problem but only when compiling for iOS Device, not for the simulators. I'm not able to create an archive.

PLESE HELP ME!

**SOLVED**

The problem was due to a "Run Script" in Build Phases I was forgotten....and that pointed to the old path /Developer

Comment: After the Clean, the problem persist

Comment: You mentioned you get a different load command error (10). Can you post the **whole** error log, when performing a build. Thank you

Comment: It sounds like perhaps it's running the wrong codesign_allocate.

Comment: Having the same issue, can you please specify exactly what you changed to solve?

Comment: @gavrix, An year ago I've added a code for build an ipa for jailbroken device, after purchased the license I forgot to remove this code. It uses the _/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform_ path, but the current Xcode version uses the path _/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform_. I've removed this code because I need it no more, it is in **Build Phases** tab of your project details. To understand what I'm talking about refer to this [link](http://www.alexwhittemore.com/developing-jailbroken-iphone-ios-401/#more-398)

Comment: thanks, this info might help me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your derived data, perform a clean build, and try again.

1. To delete your derived data, go to Organizer->Projects, and select `Delete...'

   [image: Delete derived data screen]
2. To do a clean build, select Project in Xcode, and select "Clean"

   [image: How to do a clean build, Shift+Cmd+K]

**Update:** Validating your project settings may help here also. Go to your Project file in Xcode and select it.

[image: Validate project settings]

**Update 2:** Something seems to be interfering with `codesign`, causing it to use an incorrect loading command. Maybe your old version of Xcode (4.4) left some artifacts behind, which is causing an old version of `codesign` to be run. I'd suggest uninstalling any instances of Xcode you have, make sure they're all gone, then re-install the latest version.

**Update 3:** I'm at a loss, I've no idea what's going on. My last suggestion is to create a new Xcode project, and migrate your stuff over; something may have interfered with your build settings, which might be a case of looking for a needle in a haystack. Make sure you have the latest Xcode and OS X.

Comment: @user915829 Are you sure you deleted your Derived Data?

Comment: Delete button for Derived Data section is disabled, I've performed only the cleansing

Comment: Ummm. In Terminal, run `rm -rf /Users/myUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` to make sure. This is safe; derived data can be re-built.

Comment: Derive Data deleted, cleansing performed, but the problem persist. Note: I've changed the SDK and and deployment target to 6.0, now the error finish with `(unknown load command 10)`

Comment: @user915829 What version of OS X are you using, as well as Xcode version?

Comment: Have you validated your project settings? Check my answer to see how

Comment: @user915829 As mentioned, can you post the whole error log that you're getting? There may be something we're missing.

Comment: @user915829 Updated answer again, I don't notice anything untoward in the error log. Basically, you might need to re-install Xcode to start fresh, making sure any old versions of Xcode have been removed beforehand.

Comment: I've removed 4.5.1 version and installed 4.5.2 version of Xcode, but the problem persist :(

Comment: Maybe I miss something....after the previous two error messages, there is a line highlighted in red: `Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1`

Comment: Another update.... It was selected iOS Device.... changing it to iPhone Simulater now it compile -.-" What I am missing?

Comment: I've read the update, but I don't know. My last suggestion is to create a new Xcode project, and migrate your stuff over, something may have interfered with your build settings, which might be looking for a needle in a haystack. Make sure you have the latest Xcode and OS X. If that doesn't work, then I'm at a complete loss. I'll update the answer with this suggestion.

Comment: I've found this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425840/that-codesign-returned-1-object-ifile-format-invalid-or-unsuitable-problem-aga), It talks about path /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform .. I haven't this path but I have /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform ..

Comment: That's because the link is out of date, previous Xcodes installed in `/Developer`, whereas now it's all self contained in the `Xcode.app`. Also, `Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1` is a very generic error message, all it suggests is that the command failed.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496100/mac-load-commands-corruption